# Sockets and threads

Tags: c++, linux, performance, sockets

I have a lot of 'clients' which runs in different threads and connects to different local servers.

How bad is ~20k sockets to store in system? (linux). And how bad is ~20k threads?

The main question is about sockets, thanks.

Comment: Some of this depends on your server. When you say 'local servers' though, do you mean on the same box. Or do you mean other physical boxes that are nearby, network-wise?

Comment: @NathanielFord on the same box

Comment: epoll is what you need, baby - http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 20K socket issue is known as the [C10K](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) problem, and is well documented. Basically, with careful programming, and big enough system, you can make it.

The 20K thread issue is a different one. It really depends upon the operating systam and what kind of threads. I would suggest to have less threads than sockets.